# Selecting object with smallest dimensions/bounding box

Tags: python

OK, I have multiple objects selected and I need to get the smallest object out of those. How do I get the smallest object out of the selected objects? This is prolly simple and I just can't figure out how.

[image: Smallest Selection]

Comment: "Biggest" how? Biggest volume or biggest single dimension? Local or global?

Comment: The overall size ,so I assume volume. I was actually thinking wrong and I need the smallest. Would a picture help any?

Comment: To confirm: A 1000 x 1000 plane has zero volume, so it would be smaller than default cube?

Comment: I added a picture to original post. In this example I would need the smallest plane(which is highlighted) selected, then select the next smallest, etc. It won't always be planes used though.